# Wordpress always redirects to /wp-login.php

Tags: wordpress, authentication

i have a problem with one of my wordpress websites. Every time i want to open to home url it automatically redirects me to the /wp-login.php with this strange url: 
https://example.at/wp-login.php?redirect_to=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.at%2F&reauth=1

Also i can't use the "Back to example.at" Link under the login window.

Site & Home URL are set correctly, also there is no redirection set in any plugin or in the .htacces. Also all safety plugins are disabled.

Does anyone already had this strange problem?

Comment: remove wp-include and wp-admin folder and other files in the root except for wp-config.php and htaccess, and upload the latest version again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that your website plugins works good.

1. For first disable all plugins or rename **/wp-content/plugins** folder then check your website. If problem solves rename back the plugins folder and try to rename plugins directories step by step and find problematic plugin.
2. Try change the main theme and recheck problem, look at your main theme **function.php** file content, if you see the obfuscated codes, delete this codes and recheck website.
3. Delete **wp-include**, **wp-admin** folders and reupload from offical wordpress.org last version archive,
4. Install **Wordfence** av plugin and scan your website files. maybe you have injected codes.
5. check your **.htaccess** file, try to reset it.
6. Check your server and wordpress requirements. Change the **php version to 7.2**.
7. Disable your cahce plugins (if you have).

Try to debug your website with this steps.